# Cluster markers dont show until async task finishes

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

My app works like this:

```
1- OnCreate: creates a google map
2- OnStart: add cluster items from sqlite database and show them on map
3- OnResume: an asynctask updates the sqlite database getting the data from internet and refreshes the activity
```

Everything works greate but if the user uses the app with a low internet connection and restarts the activity (by rotating the screen) before the async is finished, the map is recreated but markers dont show until async finishes.

Of course i want the markers to be shown all the time regardless if the async has finished or not.

I think there is a theorical explanation to this behavior so maybe i dont need to post any code, but if you need some code anyway ask me for it.

Thank you!

Edited:

```
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    updateMarkers();
    }

public void updateMarkers(){

        mClusterManager.clearItems();

        String[] campos = new String[] { "id", "lat", "longi" };
        String[] arg = new String[] {"borrado"};

        Cursor c = db.query("Sordos", campos, "estado <> ?", arg, null, null, null);


        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            // Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
            do {
                int id = c.getInt(0);
                String lat = c.getString(1);
                String longi = c.getString(2);


                Double l1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                Double l2 = Double.parseDouble(longi);

                MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(new LatLng(l1, l2), id);

                mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);

            } while (c.moveToNext());

            mClusterManager.cluster();
        }
}
```

Comment: `mClusterManager.cluster();` might help?

Comment: No. It seems that nothing related to the ClusterManager works until the asynctask finishes.

Comment: Your problem seems to be in the OnStart of your activity. Can you show it?

Comment: Solved reading this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190152/adding-items-to-cluster-manager-call-to-cluster-have-no-effect-until-asyncta

Comment: Oh so it was a matter of the executor. good job